# how to number the datas from mysql

Tags: mysql, row-number

This is a doubt on mysql select query
  let me axplain my doubt with a simple example
  consider this is my query
  `SELECT dbCountry from tableCountry`

tableCountry  has fields dbCuntryId, dbCountry and dbState
I have the result as

```
dbCountry 
india 
america 
england
kenya 
pakisthan
```

I need the result as

```
1  india 
2  america 
3  england
4  kenya 
5  pakisthan
```

the numbers 12345 must be generated with the increase in data and it is not an autoincrement id.
How can i get it 
is it something like loop

Comment: is that a function RowNumber() the numbers must be generated fronm query

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: How do you expect your countries to be sorted?

Comment: If those numbers is not related with actual data - you'd better put that number at DB client side. If you need to have stable relation within number and country you should store it in DB, because order of result and adding/removing entries will probably change that numbering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT dbCountry,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableCountry t2 WHERE t2.dbCountry <= t1.dbCountry) 
AS RowNum
FROM tableCountry t1
ORDER BY dbCountry
```

Answer (score 3):

The following should do what you need. It uses a variable that is incremented and returned for each row:

```
SELECT
  @rownum:=@rownum+1 number,
  c.dbCountry
FROM
  tableCountry c,
  (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
```

If you want the result to always be in the same order you'll need to add an order by constraint to the query, for example, `ORDER BY c.dbCountry` to order by the country name.